# Unable to find url to start my application deployed on jboss EAP 6.3

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web, jboss

I have deployed an application on JBOSS EAP 6.3, but I am unable to access it.

I have deployed myApp.ear.
Structure:

myApp.ear -
1. META-INF

- a. application.xml

  2. myApp.war.
- a. WEB-INF
- i. web.xml
- ii. jboss-web.xml
- iii. jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Content of application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             version="5"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
             id="Application_ID">

  <description>Test app</description>
  <display-name>My App</display-name>

  <module id="WebModule_2">
    <web>
      <web-uri>myApp.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>myapp</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>

</application>
```

Content of web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID">
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CServRespFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>BusinessNetwork</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSAMLAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>BusinessNetwork</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BusinessNetwork</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.CAppServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BusinessNetwork</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/BusinessNetwork</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

URL, I am trying: http://localhost:8080/myapp/BusinessNetwork, but the response I am getting is: JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404

There is no error while deploying the ear. Also, I can see few other services running in console.
Can anyone please tell me, what I am missing here?

Comment: can you access http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: yes, i can.Also, I have deployed helloworld quickstart example and i can access: http://localhost:8080/jboss-helloworld/HelloWorld but unable to access my app.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/myapp/BusinessNetwork  can you try this link?

Comment: it also gives same result. I have tried with  
localhost:8080/myapp/BusinessNetwork,  
localhost:8080/myApp.war/BusinessNetwork but neither of them worked